# react-native-firebase/auth sendSignInLinkToEmail not sending email link

Tags: react-native, email, firebase-authentication

I have integrated the @react-native-firebase/auth package for signing in with an email link. I have also whitelisted the domain. But the link was not sent to the respective mail. No error logs were found. Below is the action code setting and function invoked.

```js
const actionCodeSettings = {
      handleCodeInApp: true,
      url: Config.WEB_URL,
      iOS: {
        bundleId: APP_BUNDLE_ID,
      },
      android: {
        packageName: APP_BUNDLE_ID,
        installApp: true,
      },
    };
 await auth().sendSignInLinkToEmail(userEmail, actionCodeSettings);
```